# Wordpress PHP validation using Modal Contact form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

Hi im just new to wordpress i'm just confused on how to link my php validation in wordpress.
i have a send.php in my root folder located in wordpress\wp-content\themes\myTheme. my problem is that whenever i click submit in my contact form. it redirects me to the pa Object not found which in fact the send.php is located. am i doing something wrong? or i linked it incorrectly? here is my code for my Modal Contact Form.

```
<div class = "modal fade" id = "contact" role = "dialog">
      <div class = "modal-dialog">
          <div class = "modal-content">
            <div class = "modal-header">
              <h4>Message Me :3 </h4>
            </div>
              <div class = "modal-body">

                 <form class="form-horizontal" name="commentform" method="post" action="send.php">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="first_name">First Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="email">Email Address</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="comment">Question or Comment</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <textarea rows="6" class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Your question or comment here"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </form>



              </div>
```

and here is my send.php code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "ccmanere@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||        
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required    
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z\s.'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";   
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
sleep(2);
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=\"0; url=http://tutsme-webdesign.info/index.php\">";
?>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Based on the fact that your form is in a modal window you should be using ajax. The page refresh after submitting the form would close the modal window and the user would not be able to see the success message. Regarding your send.php file, if you embed your contact form in a custom page template, i would strongly suggest to keep the validation on the same file just before the get_header call

Comment: thank you for the response @antonio83. okay i'll edit and inform you if its working. thank you